# How to launch two executable on StartUp in UWP(Desktop Bridge)?

Tags: c#, uwp, desktop-bridge

I had a win32 project that had two executable and I am trying to convert the Win32 to UWP using Desktop Bridge. Is it possible to have the UWP launch both executable. I was able to execute one but I need to launch both..

```
<Applications>
<Application Id="App" Executable="$targetnametoken$.exe" EntryPoint="$targetentrypoint$">
  <uap:VisualElements DisplayName="AppName" Description="AppName" BackgroundColor="transparent" Square150x150Logo="Images\Square150x150Logo.png" Square44x44Logo="Images\Square44x44Logo.png">
    <uap:DefaultTile Wide310x150Logo="Images\Wide310x150Logo.png">
    </uap:DefaultTile>
  </uap:VisualElements>
  <Extensions>
    <desktop:Extension Category="windows.startupTask"  Executable="Images\App1.exe" EntryPoint="Windows.FullTrustApplication">
      <desktop:StartupTask TaskId="App1" Enabled="true" DisplayName="app1.exe" />
    </desktop:Extension>
    <desktop:Extension Category="windows.startupTask"  Executable="Images\App2.exe" EntryPoint="Windows.FullTrustApplication">
      <desktop:StartupTask TaskId="App2" Enabled="true" DisplayName="app2.exe" />
    </desktop:Extension>
  </Extensions>
```

Comment: I just tested it and it works fine for me. Here is my complete test project for your reference: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AovTwKUMywTNv7hOoas3F93JAXvjaw  
If your problem still persists, please share your repro project and provide additional information about what your see on your system: (1) what version of Windows 10, Visual Studio and the Windows SDK are you using? (2) does the startup tab in TaskManager show both of your startup tasks? Are both executables set up to be included in the app package?

Comment: it worked. I had to update my OS and SDK. Thanks

Comment: Yes, there was a bug in the past that you were likely running into. Posted an answer now. Just for confirmation: do you know what build you were running earlier?

Answer (score 0):

After running Stefan sample code, I got a warning that my OS and SDK was not compatible. updated both and it works...

Answer (score 0):

I looked it up and there was a bug in earlier builds (14393) that affected scenarios with multiple StartupTasks. It has been fixed in later builds, so on current builds you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am wondering why the latest releases are not backward compatible. At least to Windows 10 version.